# Continuous signal transmission in Vector CANoe

Tags: simulation, capl, canoe

I have created a node in CANoe by using Vector software and I asigned the designed database for it.

I need to transmit a continuous messages, for that I created a panel with button. When I keep pressing on the buton the signal of the message should always take the value 1 otherwise its 0 (button released)

The message that should be transmitted have this caraczeristics:

[image]

My code for transmetting the message after pressing the button :

```
variables {

 message messageDeclaredInDb myMessage;
 msTimer cyclicTimer200ms;
}
on envVar ev_Button_Status
{

  switch (getValue(this)) {

   case 0: myMessage.Sig = 0;
           write("button released");
           break;

    case 1: myMessage.Sig = 1;
            write("button pressed");
            break;

    default: write("Default");
  }

  setTimerCyclic(cyclicTimer200ms, 200);

}

on timer cyclicTimer200ms 
{

  myMessage.Sig = getValue(ev_Button_Status);
  output(myMessage); 
}
```

And I visualize the result in the Graphics:

[image]

But the wanted result should be like this without the up and down of the signal:

[image]

Any tips please? knowing that I don't use any Interaction Layer.

Answer (score 3):

Note the `GenMsgILSupport = Yes` attribute, meaning the **Interaction Layer** support is enabled for this message. The IL is responsible for receiving and transmitting messages according to the attributes (like cycle time) defined in the database.

Using IL support, you can access the signals directly. You neither need to define message variables nor timers, just put a `$` character before the signal name and set the value. Example:

```c
 $Sig = 1;
```

Complete example 1:

```c
on envVar ev_Button_Status
{    
     switch (getValue(this)) {    
     case 0:
         $Sig = 0;
         write("button released");
         break;

      case 1:
          $Sig = 1;
          write("button pressed");
          break;

      default:
          write("Default");
    }    
}
```

---

**If you don't use any Interaction Layer**, make sure it is disabled for your message. Furthermore, the are some issues with you code:

1. You should start the timer in `on start`, not in `on envVar`.
2. Set the signal value in `on envVar` or `on timer`, but not in both.

Complete example 2:

```c
variables {
    message messageDeclaredInDb myMessage;
    msTimer cyclicTimer200ms;
}

on start
{
    setTimerCyclic(cyclicTimer200ms, 200);
}

on timer cyclicTimer200ms 
{
    myMessage.Sig = getValue(ev_Button_Status);
    output(myMessage);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! Actually the problem was that the ECU was physically connected while I was trying to simulated it, so I was sending the signal, and at the same time the ECU is also sending the signal. That's why we get this behavior on the graph!